# pscp works for one account but does not work for another

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, putty, scp

I have two accounts A, B both registered on the windows server 2008 R2. There is a script in which I use pscp module of putty to transfer files from the server.

Problem being that the command runs successfully using user account A but gets stuck using account B. The command does not complete using user account B

I have to manually terminate it.

Both accounts have the below privilege in group policy and computer management.

Administrator
Logon as a batch
Replace process level token
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. When we use pscp alone on command prompt , this is the prompt we get

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You have no
>   guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is. The
>   server's rsa2 key fingerprint is: ssh-rsa 1024
>   cc:78:13:a3:68:a6:59:7e:b8:23:2d:13:3e:66:9b:b9 If you trust this
>   host, enter "y" to add the key to PuTTY's cache and carry on
>   connecting. If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n". If you do not trust this host,
>   press Return to abandon the connection. Store key in cache? (y/n)
>   Connection abandoned.

We need to press y/n and the command shall thereafter proceed.

While this command was running in the script , the prompt was not getting any input from the user and was therefore never ending.

To mitigate this

one can do something like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576700/how-to-pass-value-to-psftp-prompt